# Setting GitHub ID in plutus-playground-server local env

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I have been able to get my local nix install of the server and client running on my ubuntu distro. However, I can't find where I can set the `GitHub ID` for the local server configuration and that is one of 2 errors when the server starts. I already have set my `git config --global user.name` before the nix setup, but I don't think it is calling that git info. Is this doable with a local nix/playground install? If so, how?
Thanks for any advice you may have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this. If you have wanted to debug these errors like myself, don't sweat it.

After watching Lars complete the build and the output on his screen after Lesson#1, Part#3 (L1P3) video, I realized these errors seem 'normal' at this point in the build. Please verify for yourself, but I believe there is nothing to see here.